# R formula() dummy coding model matrix factor interactions

Tags: r, formula, model.matrix

I'm attempting to use `formula` to generate a `model.matrix` object to be used in a custom optimizer function.

It works great for the most part, but when it comes to factor-factor interactions, I'd like to specify the interaction as dummy coded rather than effects coded.

Take for example the following data set:

```
set.seed(1987)
myDF <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(100),
               X1 = factor(LETTERS[sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)]),
               X2 = factor(LETTERS[sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)]))

head(myDF)
```

Both the `:` and `/` operators create an effects coded model matrix (the latter being an additive effects structure, I think).

```
head(model.matrix(formula(Y ~ X1 : X2), data = myDF))
head(model.matrix(formula(Y ~ X1 / X2), data = myDF))
```

But I am looking to generate a dummy coded model matrix, which would have the first level of `X1` omitted for each level of `X2`. Resulting in these terms (columns):

X1B:X2A

X1C:X2A

X1B:X2B

X1C:X2B

X1B:X2C

X1C:X2C

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Is `~X1:X2-1` what you're looking for?

Make test data (as above):

```
set.seed(1987)
myDF <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(100),
          X1 = factor(LETTERS[sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)]),
          X2 = factor(LETTERS[sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)]))
```

Generate model matrix:

```
mm1 <- model.matrix(formula(Y ~ X1 : X2 - 1), data = myDF)
head(mm1)
##   X1A:X2A X1B:X2A X1C:X2A X1A:X2B X1B:X2B X1C:X2B X1A:X2C X1B:X2C X1C:X2C
## 1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
## 2       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
## 3       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
## 4       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
## 5       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
## 6       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
```

Or perhaps you really do just want some columns excluded:

```
mm0 <- model.matrix(formula(Y ~ X1 : X2), data = myDF)
mm0B <- mm0[,!grepl("(Intercept|^X1A:)",colnames(mm0))]
##   X1B:X2A X1C:X2A X1B:X2B X1C:X2B X1B:X2C X1C:X2C
## 1       0       0       1       0       0       0
## 2       0       0       0       0       0       0
## 3       0       0       0       0       1       0
## 4       0       0       0       1       0       0
## 5       0       0       0       0       0       0
## 6       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

I thought you also might be interested in sum-to-zero contrasts:

```
 mm2 <- model.matrix(formula(Y ~ X1 : X2 - 1), data = myDF,
                     contrasts.arg=list(X1=contr.sum,X2=contr.sum))
```

Comment: What you have in your `mm0B` object is exactly what I'm looking for in terms of output. I guess I was hoping there was a way to do this directly in the `formula` or `model.matrix` call, since I won't necessarily know what the variables of the RHS of the formula will be named or what class they will be. Dropping the intercept is doable as you demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

Below is another trial.

```
set.seed(1987)
myDF <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(100),
                   X1 = factor(LETTERS[sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)]),
                   X2 = factor(LETTERS[sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)]))
# row subsetting to exclude A
modelMat <- model.matrix(formula(Y ~ X1 : X2), data = myDF[myDF$X1 != 'A',])
# column subsetting to eliminate all columns including X1A
modelMat <- modelMat[,substring(colnames(modelMat), 1, 3) != "X1A"]
head(modelMat)
   (Intercept) X1B:X2A X1C:X2A X1B:X2B X1C:X2B X1B:X2C X1C:X2C
1            1       0       0       1       0       0       0
3            1       0       0       0       0       1       0
4            1       0       0       0       1       0       0
8            1       0       0       0       0       1       0
10           1       0       0       0       0       0       1
11           1       0       0       0       0       0       1
```